# Rigorous proof of Gauss's law

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, physics, surface-integrals

It is known that Gauss's law for the electrostatic field $\mathbf{E}$, in the SI, is given by the equation

$$
\int_S \mathbf{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{a}=4\pi k_e Q_{\text{ encl}} \tag{1}
$$

where $k_e$ it is the electric constant, $S$ it is the gausssian surface and $Q_{\text{ encl}}$ is the quantity of charge contained inside $S$. What is the general rigorous proof-explanation of the $(1)$?

Being that $\int_S \mathbf{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{a}=\int_S E_x(da)_x+E_y(da)_y+E_z(da)_z$ is there some correlations, for the proof, with the differential quadratic forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss's law is equivalent to divergence theorem and since since $\nabla \mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho(\vec P)}{\epsilon_0}$ we have

$$\int_S \mathbf{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{a}=\int_V \nabla \mathbf{E}\, dV=\int_V \frac{\rho(\vec P)}{\epsilon_0} \, dV=\frac{Q_{ \text{ encl} }}{\epsilon_0}=4\pi k_e Q_{ \text{ encl} }$$

Comment: In the meantime, I would like to thank you for your answer. Personally, I always vote in favour of the answers given (if they are coherent) and I have also voted for others of yours previously. When I was a boy my professor of General Physics II said in class that there is a very long proof to prove equality. Yours is very simple since it is an application of one of the 4 laws of Maxwell. Thanks again and I hope you enjoyed my comment.

Comment: @Sebastiano You are welcome! Are you looking for something different? Bye

Comment: You are...always welcome. In the net I have not find anything. Thank you very much and most greetings.